# How to reconstruct source document from embeddings chroma DB?

Tags: python, embedding, langchain, py-langchain, chromadb

Is there built in functionality in Chroma DB to be able to reconstruct a document from the chunks stored in chromadb in a reliable way?

The `Chroma().get()` method from langchain returns a dict with the entries
Assume the original document data.txt reads "data1 data2 data3"

```
{
    "documents": [
        "data1","data2","data3"
    ],
    "embeddings": null,
    "ids": [
        uuid1,uuid2,uuid3
    ],
    "metadatas": [
        {
            "source": "data.txt"
        },
        {
            "source": "data.txt"
        },
        {
            "source": "data.txt"
        },
    ]
}
```

How do we merge the embeddings correctly to recreate the source document data.txt?

Assuming that they are correctly sorted from the beginning I suppose a loop can be made to do this. The only problem is that some of the elements in the "documents" array have some overlapping substrings in the beginning and end. I'm not doing any custom chunking so I don't know how many characters the overflow is and it is not constant, it varies in some elements. I guess a fix could be to manually do the chunking and know the overlap.

Is there a more generalized way or one provided by chroma or langchain?

Comment: why you want to do this, as you might already have original source documents

Comment: Yes that is the solution I'm looking at if there is not a better way.
However that would require extra storage. My flow right now is upload file, create embeddings, add to chroma, delete file.

Answer (score 2):

There's no requirement that the metadata be strictly a filename.  So if you're putting in substrings of the exact literal text, you could encode the starting positions in the metadata.  Like:

```
"metadatas": [
    {
        "source": "data.txt:0"
    },
    {
        "source": "data.txt:498"
    },
    {
        "source": "data.txt:992"
    },
]
```

(Those positions are bigger than the sizes of your examples "data1 data2 data3" -- I'm pretending it's a bigger document.)

Then when you read it out (let's say you put the relevant parts into variables `chunks` and `sources`), you could do something like:

```
chunk_info = []
for (chunk, source) in zip(chunks, sources):  # assumes `chunks` and `sources` extracted from the `Chroma().get()` call
    filename_start_ix = source.rsplit(':', 1)
    if len(filename_start_ix) != 2 or (not filename_start_ix[1].isdigit()):
        ValueError('Invalid source format')
    chunk_info.append((chunk, filename_start_ix[0], int(filename_start_ix[1])))

chunk_info.sort(key=lambda info: info[2])  # sort by position in chunk
chunk_info.sort(key=lambda info: info[1])  # sort by filename (maybe you don't need to support multiple files, but this will)

documents = {}  # gather them in a dict in case there's more than one file in the mix
for (chunk, filename, start_ix) in chunk_info:
    document = documents.get(filename, '')
    doc_len = len(document)
    if doc_len > start_ix:
        document = document[:start_ix]  # remove overlap (assumes overlap is the same)
    elif doc_len < start_ix:
        document += ' ' * (start_ix - doc_len)  # fill in gaps with spaces
    documents[filename] = document + chunk
```

That's just a quick-and-dirty example to demonstrate the point.  There are other ways you could do it.  But if the data's all in there, you should be able to reconstruct it one way or another.

Answer (score 0):

I think there is no such default functions available in chromadb. If you want to store any text data and retrieve them, they provide metadata option where you can store and filter the data using built-in functionalities. But I have read about decoding embeddings the below links could be helpful -> https://community.openai.com/t/is-it-possible-to-convert-vector-to-text/312794/20